# How to get products with the available dates?

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.3, products, search

I have created product attributes "Available from" and "Available to" with the input types **date**.

I want to get products from the available dates while searching.

How can I achieve that result?

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Special/blob/master/Model/Layer.php#L65-L99

```
            $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

            $date = new \Zend_Date();

            $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
                'special_from_date',
                [
                    'or' => [
                        0 => [
                            'date' => true,
                            'to' => $date->get('YYYY-MM-dd') . ' 23:59:59'
                        ],
                        1 => [
                            'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                'left'
            );

            $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
                'special_to_date',
                [
                    'or' => [
                        0 => [
                            'date' => true,
                            'from' => $date->get('YYYY-MM-dd') . ' 00:00:00'
                        ],
                        1 => [
                            'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                'left'
            );
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try and update